# Integrating Two Different Methods of Measuring Velocity

Tags: average, time-series

I am using two different methods to measure velocity. (Here, I’m measuring velocity in one dimension, with velocity in one direction counted as positive and velocity in the other direction counted as negative.) One method (‘Method 1’) measures low velocities (and no velocity) accurately, but it cannot measure velocities that are large in magnitude (in either the positive or the negative direction) accurately. The other method (‘Method 2’) measures velocities that are large in magnitude accurately but does not measure low velocities accurately.

I want to integrate these two different methods to generate velocity values that are accurate across all velocities. These integrated values will weigh method 1 values more heavily if the method 1 values are low, and they will weigh method 2 values more heavily if the method 2 values are large in magnitude. If the method 1 value is 0, its weight would be 1 and the method 2 value wouldn’t be counted at all. If the method 2 value is infinite (which obviously isn't possible, but I'm just mentioning the case here to help to illustrate my point), its weight would be 1 and the method 1 value wouldn't be counted at all.

What is the best way to integrate both of these methods?

The best solution I have at the moment is to transform both method 1 and method 2 values separately so they're on a finite scale. Since I want to base one of my weighing parameters off of infinite values, I need to make both positive and negative infinity finite values. By transforming them with [the logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) or [some other sigmoid function that is continuous, differentiable, and has asymptotes at 0 and 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function), values that were negative infinity become 0, values that were 0 become 0.5, and values that were positive infinity become 1. Now, with both method 1 and method 2 values on the same finite scale, I can apply the weights: method 1 would have a weight of 1 if its transformed value is 0.5 and a weight of 0 if its transformed value is either 0 or 1, and method 2 would have a weight of 1 if its transformed value is either 0 or 1 and a weight of 0 if its transformed value is 0.5. I'm not sure which sigmoid function is most appropriate or how quickly it should approach the asymptotes - is there a way to determine these things using the data?

I also asked this same question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/621423/integrating-two-different-methods-of-measuring-velocity).

Comment: Some small numerical examples are helping us to understand what your goal is. The R-code  is not sufficient.

Comment: @callculus42 - thanks. Is this spreadsheet better?

Comment: Yes, but I haven't looked at it closely yet.

Comment: The best hybrid method will depend on the precise nature of the inaccuracies in methods 1 and 2. What counts as 'low' and 'high' for each method? Does accuracy shrink slowly or drop off immediately? What is the ratio of method 1 inaccuracy to method 2 inaccuracy at different scales? Can we predict if the inaccuracies are biased in a positive/negative way, or correlated with each other between the methods?

Comment: I like Ray's idea in the linked question, but I have to wonder how you're supposed to use speed to decide whether to use Method 1 or Method 2 data when it's speed we're trying to figure out in the first place. If both methods' measured velocities at a given time indicate the velocity is in the range of one method's accuracy range but not the other, then the answer is clear, but I dunno about otherwise.

Comment: @coiso - those questions are very good. I don't have a good answer for any of them. It probably depends on how the sensors are installed and therefore the answers probably differ with each experiment. I do know that method 1 is probably more accurate for low velocities than method 2 is for high velocities. I guess for now I will tinker around with some of the sigmoid curves I mentioned in my original question. I'm hoping to find out how to parameterize those sigmoid curves in a way that makes theoretical sense, although since I can't answer your questions, I may not be able to do that. Thanks!

Comment: I have an idea to work backwards: assume you know the true velocity $v$, develop a model to predict what the two methods yield, and choose the $v$ that maximizes the likelihood of observing what you observed.
$$v = \arg \max_v P_1(v_1|v) \times P_2(v_2|v) \\
P_1(v_1|v) = e^{-\frac{v_1^2}{\sigma_1}}, \quad \sigma_1 = \frac{1}{\eta_1} - 1, \quad \eta_1 = e^{-\frac{v^2}{\sigma}}
$$
Though I'm not writing an answer because I'm not happy with my current choice for $P_1(v_1|v)$

Comment: @TonyMathew - it's not practical to conduct a calibration to measure true velocities for every study I do, but I agree that knowing how measurements from methods A and B compare to true velocities would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this problem by seeing the weight function as curves. There will be one velocity where both the measurements will give the same value, and this will be the accurate value of the velocity.

As infinity is an impractical limit, a linear curve for weights may not make sense as it will bias the low velocity measurements more in the practical range. I would suggest a cubic or quartic function depending on your working range of velocities. The coefficients of the cubic curve will be dependent on the velocity of equal measurement. Please refer to the following illustration of the idea.

[image: The illustration of idea]

The dotted lines show the linear weights and the advantages of cubic or higher degree weight is clear from the picture.

Hope this helps

Comment: Linear, quadratic, cubic, quartic, and other polynomial functions aren't vertically bounded by 0 and 1, so for velocities that are large in magnitude, they would not be able to assign weights that are between 0 and 1. I know I could parameterize these polynomials to ensure they are between 0 and 1 (vertically) over all the velocities I've measured (my measured velocities will have a finite range), but I want to develop a robust method that can account for any velocity.

Comment: You can use a sigmoid function or the derivative of sigmoid function. This way all the velocities are guaranteed with the velocities out of practical range having a bias of almost 1 beyond a threshold. https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:4800/format:webp/1\*6A3A_rt4YmumHusvTvVTxw.png

Comment: Using the derivatives of sigmoid functions instead of polynomials for assigning weights is a great idea